# Compare date of each contract in df with the each contract of that company across categories

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am interested to see all contracts that have dates < 60 days appart for the same supplier, but in different categories.

My dataset structure looks like this (simpliyfied):

```
ContractID, Date, Company, Category
```

First steps I took was to Sort the df by Company and Date.

Now I would just like to keep the contracts for each Company that is under 60 days apart with another contract in a different category, but the same company. So if the contract is 10 days apart with the same company, but its in the same Category it should not show up.

So after grouping by Company each check for each row within that group should be: Is there another contract with the same company that is under 60 days apart? If yes, does this other contract belong to a different Category? If yes keep it in df otherwise drop.

It would already be helpful to point me to the correct functions within pandas to do this.

Example:

```
Contract 1, 01.01.2018, Company A, Category A
Contract 2,  01.02.2018, Company A, Category A
Contract 3,  10.06.2018, Company A, Category B
Contract 4,  16.07.2018, Company A, Category A
Contract 5, 17.07.2018, Company B, Category C
```

Desired Result 
Drop Contract 1 because it is only within 60 days to contract 2 and they have the same category
Drop contract 2 for the same reason
Keep contract 3 because its within 60 days to contract 4 and in a different category
same for contract 4

Comment: It's kinda hard to follow the logic without sample data and expected outputs.

Comment: @QuangHoang I was fearing that I will see if I can add something as an example

Comment: I understand why drop contract 1, but why contract 2?

Comment: @QuangHoang for the same reasons as the first one. There is only one other contract that is within 60 days, which is contract 1, but they are in the same category so it gets dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing data, I would suspect you'd want to join the dataframe to itself on company where category != category.  Then you can just do date math to find instances where there is a < 60 day difference.

EDIT:

Here's a solution I came up with that makes a function which returns a dataframe for you.

```
#sample dataframe 
'''
   ContractID       Date  Company  Category
0           1 2019-02-03        1         1
1           2 2019-02-01        1         3
2           3 2019-02-01        2         2
3           4 2018-02-01        2         3
4           5 2019-02-03        3         1
5           6 2019-02-03        3         1
'''

def contract_checker(df):

    # inner join on itself
    check = df.merge(df,how='inner',on='Company')

    # filter based on conditions
    check = check.loc[(abs(check['Date_x'] - check['Date_y']).dt.days < 60) &
                      (check['Category_x'] != check['Category_y']),:]

    # join again to filter output
    check = df.merge(check[['ContractID_x', 'Company']].rename(index=str, columns={"ContractID_x": "ContractID"}),on=['ContractID', 'Company'],how='inner')

    # return correct dataframe
    return check

df = contract_checker(df)

df

'''
output
   ContractID       Date  Company  Category
0           1 2019-02-03        1         1
1           2 2019-02-01        1         3
'''
```

Comment: added a small example which hopefully clarifies a bit. Thanks for the suggestion already

Comment: how would I go about the date math? I would somehow have to compare each date in each row with all the others with the same company I guess, but Im not sure whats the best way to go about this.

Comment: thanks for your answer, currently implementing it and it seems to do the job except for the fact that for some reason it gives me a lot of duplicates that need to be removed. I am currently working on understanding the code to find the reason, will report back when I found it, otherwise its working well!

Comment: It should give you duplicates of you don't only take one side of it. You'll see I only took side "x" at the end.  This is because I intentionally did a Cartesian join.  Otherwise if you want to share what you're using we can probably help.